# Snap Assist: Putty Window behavior

Tags: windows-10, putty, windows-snap-assist

Windows 10 Snap-Assist does not manipulate a Putty window as expected.  The normal sequence starting from full-screen is:

1. Full Screen
2. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>: Half screen
3. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>: quarter screen

Instead, with Putty:

1. Full Screen
2. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> changes to 3/4 screen and toggles from one side to another
3. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> hides the 3/4 screen

Is there a setting that configures the Putty windows to behave more like its peers? I tried to Google this but was not successful. I would think that this has already been done.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this issue at all even with a fresh download of putty.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried this on a different laptop and Putty behaved as expected.  Maybe a fresh install is what is needed on the original laptop to configure Putty.   @James: Thank you